# NSAlert won't disappear

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsalert

I'm using a simple NSAlert based on Apple's sample code, and while it displays fine, it never disappears.

Code:

```
void DisplayAlert()
{
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"TEST");
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Yay!"];
    [alert setInformativeText:@"This is an informational alert."];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSAlertStyleInformational];

    [alert runModal];

    NSLog(@"TEST2");
    [alert.window close];
    [alert release];
    NSLog(@"TEST3");
}
```

I have tried with and without the `[alert.window close]` line and neither way will the alert disappear.

I have also tried making the first line `[[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];` but that did not help, either.

All of the `NSLog` messages appear.

Comment: Use (NSAlert *) returnCode.

Comment: Where exactly? I’m not sure what you mean

Comment: void DisplayAlert() does not look like an Objective-C method in an NSObject-derived class.  Is the code running in a standard cocoa application?  We might need more context to evaluate this routine.

Comment: I'm using CGo with some bindings around the Objective C Cocoa library functions

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and struggled for a long time trying to find a way to make the dismissed alerts disappear.

My solution was to forsake NSAlert altogether in favor of CFUserNotificationAlert. [This blocking alert API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1534496-cfusernotificationdisplayalert?language=objc) or the [non-blocking CFUserNotificationNotice API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1534478-cfusernotificationdisplaynotice?language=objc) can be used to display stand-alone alert dialogs which are identical to those produced by NSAlert, but they can be dismissed unlike NSAlert dialogs when run from a simple windowless binary.

[Here's an example of CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert](http://macosx-programming.blogspot.com/2011/09/heres-sample-to-display-messagebox-with.html) and a preview of some of its code below:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main(void) {
    CFOptionFlags cfRes;

    //display alert with 5 second timeout, at NoteAlertLevel
    CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert(5, kCFUserNotificationNoteAlertLevel, 
            NULL, NULL, NULL, 
            CFSTR("Testing"), 
            CFSTR("Click on any button..."), 
            CFSTR("OK"), 
            CFSTR("Cancel"), 
            CFSTR("Test Button"), 
            &cfRes);
    return cfRes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method you need is `-orderOut:` not `-close`. Alert/Panel windows are not documents and are not "closed" in the usually sense. You just what them to disappear.